# Rails submit button text (formtastic) - how to change label of submit button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-submit, formtastic, submit-button

I am using simple_form and the following code to create the button.

```
<%= form.action :submit, :value => "submit", :button_html => { :class => "lagoon" }  %>
```

However the button is (still) labeled 'Create User' instead of 'submit'.
I thought setting the value => would do it but it didn't

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably better and correct way is to use **:label** key and keep :button_html for styling

```
<%= form.action :submit, :label => "Submit", :button_html => { :class => "lagoon" } %>
```

I think best idea is to use I18n keys. Check [Formtastic docs](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic):

Formtastic decides which label to use in the following order:

1. :label             # :label => "Choose Title"
2. Formtastic i18n    # if either :label => true || i18n_lookups_by_default = true (see Internationalization)
3. Activerecord i18n  # if localization file found for the given attribute
4. label_str_method   # if nothing provided this defaults to :humanize but can be set to a custom method

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

Answer (score 6):

Turned out I need to do:

```
<%= form.action :submit, :button_html => { :value => 'Submit', :class => "lagoon" }  %>
```

Comment: This is the only thing that actually worked for me. Thanks!